# Display JSON data in php or HTML

Tags: php, html, arrays, json

```
{ "admin": { "FNAME": "System", "LNAME": "Administrator", "PACKAGE": "default", "WEB_TEMPLATE": "default", "BACKEND_TEMPLATE": "", "PROXY_TEMPLATE": "default", "DNS_TEMPLATE": "default", "WEB_DOMAINS": "unlimited", "WEB_ALIASES": "unlimited", "DNS_DOMAINS": "unlimited", "DNS_RECORDS": "unlimited", "MAIL_DOMAINS": "unlimited", "MAIL_ACCOUNTS": "unlimited", "DATABASES": "unlimited", "CRON_JOBS": "unlimited", "DISK_QUOTA": "unlimited", "BANDWIDTH": "unlimited", "NS": "ns1.clark-chen.com,ns2.clark-chen.com", "SHELL": "sh", "BACKUPS": "3", "CONTACT": "admin@example.com", "CRON_REPORTS": "yes", "RKEY": "moEzAxtO9j", "SUSPENDED": "no", "SUSPENDED_USERS": "0", "SUSPENDED_WEB": "0", "SUSPENDED_DNS": "0", "SUSPENDED_MAIL": "0", "SUSPENDED_DB": "0", "SUSPENDED_CRON": "0", "IP_AVAIL": "2", "IP_OWNED": "2", "U_USERS": "24", "U_DISK": "1694", "U_DISK_DIRS": "235", "U_DISK_WEB": "1255", "U_DISK_MAIL": "1", "U_DISK_DB": "203", "U_BANDWIDTH": "1932", "U_WEB_DOMAINS": "14", "U_WEB_SSL": "7", "U_WEB_ALIASES": "19", "U_DNS_DOMAINS": "1", "U_DNS_RECORDS": "11", "U_MAIL_DOMAINS": "5", "U_MAIL_DKIM": "4", "U_MAIL_ACCOUNTS": "1", "U_DATABASES": "9", "U_CRON_JOBS": "8", "U_BACKUPS": "3", "LANGUAGE": "tw", "TIME": "01:02:56", "DATE": "2015-11-15" }, "test": { "FNAME": "test", "LNAME": "test2", "PACKAGE": "default", "WEB_TEMPLATE": "default", "BACKEND_TEMPLATE": "", "PROXY_TEMPLATE": "default", "DNS_TEMPLATE": "default", "WEB_DOMAINS": "unlimited", "WEB_ALIASES": "unlimited", "DNS_DOMAINS": "unlimited", "DNS_RECORDS": "unlimited", "MAIL_DOMAINS": "unlimited", "MAIL_ACCOUNTS": "unlimited", "DATABASES": "unlimited", "CRON_JOBS": "unlimited", "DISK_QUOTA": "unlimited", "BANDWIDTH": "unlimited", "NS": "ns1.example.com,ns2.example.com", "SHELL": "nologin", "BACKUPS": "3", "CONTACT": "test@test.org", "CRON_REPORTS": "yes", "RKEY": "vsZH3vrZsJ", "SUSPENDED": "no", "SUSPENDED_USERS": "0", "SUSPENDED_WEB": "0", "SUSPENDED_DNS": "0", "SUSPENDED_MAIL": "0", "SUSPENDED_DB": "0", "SUSPENDED_CRON": "0", "IP_AVAIL": "2", "IP_OWNED": "0", "U_USERS": "0", "U_DISK": "32", "U_DISK_DIRS": "1", "U_DISK_WEB": "29", "U_DISK_MAIL": "0", "U_DISK_DB": "2", "U_BANDWIDTH": "22", "U_WEB_DOMAINS": "2", "U_WEB_SSL": "0", "U_WEB_ALIASES": "2", "U_DNS_DOMAINS": "2", "U_DNS_RECORDS": "18", "U_MAIL_DOMAINS": "0", "U_MAIL_DKIM": "0", "U_MAIL_ACCOUNTS": "0", "U_DATABASES": "2", "U_CRON_JOBS": "0", "U_BACKUPS": "3", "LANGUAGE": "en", "TIME": "10:45:07", "DATE": "2015-07-20" }}`
```

`I need help on display those JSON data on either php or HTML, I just need it to be easy to look.

Comment: remove the  `  in your JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
// here $json is your json data
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($arr as $a){
    foreach($a as $key => $value){
        echo $key . " : " . $value . "<br />";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work too, if you dont mind showing the "Array" words:

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
print '<pre>';
print_r($array);
print '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [admin] => Array
    (
        [FNAME] => System
        [LNAME] => Administrator
        ...
        [TIME] => 01:02:56
        [DATE] => 2015-11-15
    )

    [test] => Array
    (
        [FNAME] => test
        [LNAME] => test2
        ...
        [TIME] => 10:45:07
        [DATE] => 2015-07-20
    )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Valid your JSON in http://jsonlint.com/

Or in http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ you can validate your json and have a view in the viewer.

Also,there is a plugin named [JSONViewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc) in chrome webstore or [JSONView addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/jsonview/) in firefox. By simply echoing the JSON and then there will be a page that you could view JSON documents in the browser.